# Recorrer valores de una lista y meterlos en una variable en Python

Tags: python-2.7

Tengo una lista con datos que quiero recorrer con un bucle for y meter ese dato en una variable.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
from Read_element_IDs import elementID
element_list = elementID()
#Comprueba importación de la lista print element_list
input_file_path = "A350-900_SMM10_I4_Exceedance_LCs_Step_7_FS_LHS.f06"
output_file_path = "EXTRACTION_FORCES_CRODS.txt"
with open(input_file_path, "r") as in_file, \
     open(output_file_path, "w") as out_file:
    i = 0
    for i in element_list:
        element_id = element_list[i]
        for line in in_file:
        #element_id = "55100515"
            if line[:26] == "      ELEMENT-ID =" + element_id:
                out_file.write(line)
                for line in in_file:
                    if line[0] == "1":
                        break
                    out_file.write(line)
                break
    else:
        print("Element was not found")
```

Me da error en element_id = element_list[i]
    element_id = element_list[i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

No entiendo por qué no está tomando i como entero

¿Cómo hago para resolverlo?

Comment: `for i in lista` te va devolviendo los valores que hay en la lista, no sus índices. Por tanto `element_id = i`, o si prefieres podrías haber hecho `for element_id in element_list`

Comment: Si, quiero los valores de la lista

Comment: Pues lo dicho, pon `for element_id in element_list` y así la variable `element_id` va tomando los valores contenidos en la lista, y la línea `element_id = element_list[i]`sobra. Tal como lo tenías, `i` ya era cada posible valor de la lista, y no el índice. Si por ejemplo, el primer elemento de la lista era "55100515", entonces en la primera iteración `i` valía "55100515", y no 0 como pareces suponer. Por eso rompía al intentar `element_list[i]`.

Comment: Manuel, acabo de ver tu última edición. ¿Has leido mi anterior comentario? el bucle `for` itera por los _valores_ de la lista, que son en tun caso cadenas, no por los _indices_. Olvídate de los índices pues sólo los usabas para acceder a los valores, pero `for` ya te da directamente los valores.

Comment: Perdona que no había leido el comentario tuyo anterior. Si funciona como dice. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El error tal y como comenta @abulafia es que cuando iteras con un `for in` sobre un iterable este ya te retorna cada item:

```
for element_id in element_list:
    ...
```

No obstante tu código no va a funcionar como esperas porque en la práctica puedes terminar buscando **solo por el primer elemento de la lista**. Esto se debe a que iteras sobre un fichero y en la primera iteración (primer id) ya recorres todo el archivo si no se encuentra la línea, en la siguiente id `for line in in_file` no va a retornar ninguna línea del fichero, ya que el cursor está al final de éste. Si lo encuentra, en las siguiente búsqueda no se va a tener en cuenta el trozo de fichero anterior al bloque encontrado del anterior id en la búsqueda del nuevo id, y así sucesivamente.

Si todas las coincidencias van al mismo fichero de salida, lo más simple es prescindir del `for` que itera sobre las id y modificar el condicional para que compruebe si existe una línea de la forma: `"      "ELEMENT-ID = {algún id de la lista}"`:

```
from Read_element_IDs import elementID


element_set = elementID()

#Comprueba importación de la lista print element_list
input_file_path = "A350-900_SMM10_I4_Exceedance_LCs_Step_7_FS_LHS.f06"
output_file_path = "EXTRACTION_FORCES_CRODS.txt"

with open(input_file_path, "r") as in_file, \
     open(output_file_path, "w") as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if line[:18] == "      ELEMENT-ID =" and line[18:].strip() in element_set:
                out_file.write(line)
                for line in in_file:
                    if line[0] == "1":
                        break
                    out_file.write(line)
```

También es necesario eliminar el último `break` si quieres que se capture más de un bloque.

Si no te importa el orden en el que se buscan las ids es más eficiente usar un conjunto (set) que una lista:

```
element_list = set(elementID())
```

Comment: Ok. No había caido en ello. Gracias @FJSevilla. Funciona correctamente.